# Set hostname via ssh error SCRIPT

Tags: hostname

im using this script to change hostname via ssh but i got some errors.

```
read -p "Insira o IP : " ip
read -p "Insira o nome do utilizador : " host
read -s -p "Insira a palavra passe : " oldpass

sshpass -p $oldpass ssh $host@$ip "cat /etc/hostname > hostname.txt"\
run="sshpass -p $oldpass ssh $host@$ip" \ 
hostn=$($run "cat hostname.txt") \ 
echo $hostn

sshpass -p $oldpass ssh  $host@$ip " \
echo "Enter new hostname: " \ 
read newhost \ 
sed -i "s/$hostn/$newhost/g" /etc/hosts \
sed -i "s/$hostn/$newhost/g" /etc/hostname \ 
echo "Your new hostname is "$newhost"" \ 
read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to reboot" \ 
reboot"
```

When i write new hostname appear that:

`unable to resolve host"=`.

But the script continued work and do reboot.

Comment: my guess is that $hostn is define in your first sshpass but the variable leave only during this execution, when you execute sshpass for the second time the variable $hostn doesn't exit anymore

Comment: A space in your password (or any globbing characters) may confuse your code as `$oldpass` in never properly quoted. Also, backslashes will not be read correctly as you're not using `-r` with `read`.  In general, your script is a quoting minefield.

Comment: Depending on your version of Linux it may serve you better to use hostnamectl to set the host name.

Comment: Since you're trying to pass multiple commands on the same line (escaping the newlines), each command has to be terminated by `;`.  Otherwise you'll be trying to execute `echo something read newhost sed ...` etc. as a single command.

Comment: Thanks for your help i already put script working Its more simple and work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing name in /etc/hostname file use below command to change hostname if it is a RHEL7/CentOs7 machine

hostnamectl set-hostname $newhost